# Using a non-thread-safe component with a multithread component (Design)

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety

### Design problem :

Using a **non-thread-safe** component (Collection, API, ...) in/with a **multithread** component ...

### Example :

**component1** : A multithread **socket server** who send messages ... to a message handler

**component2** : A non-thread-safe **message handler** who process messages ... from a server

### My solution :

Adding a thread-safe component ( **buffer** ) between the server and the message handler, the buffer will receive messages in **multithread** manner from the server and send them in the **same order** to the message handler in a **single thread** manner.

### My question :

Is there a better solution ? an appropriate design pattern may be **proxy** or **pipeline** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very nice option for this is to use a [Producer/Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern.

In this case, the multithreaded sockets can act as multiple producers into a guarded buffer, and your non-threadsafe message handler can consume messages in its own thread, completely synchronously.  This provides a very clean way to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the "message queue" approach: works reliably, good de-coupling characteristics  and is simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

One common approach is to simply guard the non-thread safe API with coarse grained locks or create a thin wrapper that takes care of the locking

Answer (score 1):

Depending on **what makes the Component2 not thread-safe** ...

Creating instances of your component2 as needed :
Each instance is accessed only by one thread, so your system might behave correctly as a whole. You can analyze if it is ok...